# how to determine how big the current uncommitted sql transaction will be

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, transaction-log

I found a blog a while back that had the sql to determine how expensive updating a clustered index was.   Sql will do a delete and a insert.

It did something like this:

```
begin trans
update mytable set myclusteredindexColumn = 'abc' where myclusteredindexColumn = 'abc'
```

Query the DMV or something to show how expensive this is and don't commit.

Does anyone know how to determine how large the transaction log will be for the current uncommitted transaction?

-Randy

Comment: I have never worried about the size of the transaction at the granular of a level. Not sure what is to be gained from that. Logically it would be the size of the original data (the entire row) plus the size of the new data (again the entire row) plus a few bytes for overhead. In the grand scheme of things the transaction log size for single row update is pretty much nothing unless you have a lot of MAX columns.

Comment: Here is the script I came up with .  Never could find that blog, but I think this is what I was looking for.

select database_transaction_log_bytes_used  
from sys.dm_tran_database_transactions 
where transaction_id = 
(SELECT  top 1 DTST.[transaction_id]  
FROM     sys.[dm_tran_session_transactions]  AS DTST
WHERE   DTST.[session_id] =  @@SPID) 
and database_id = DB_ID()